# For loops and time series plots

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, time-series

I'm new to coding and am trying to make a time series scatterplot. I have hourly ozone concentrations from every day of the year for 12 years. I have calculated average and max values for each month of the year and am trying to compare the monthly average and monthly max data. I want to make 3 separate scatterplots for April, May, and June (so each graph should have two lines, avg and max). Here's what I've done so far:

```
#earlier in the code I specified only the months of Apr, May, Jun using:

df = df[df.month.isin([4, 5, 6])].copy()

#more code involving calculations, fast forward:

for month in avg_MDA8.month.unique():
    for month in max_MDA8.month.unique():
        data1 = avg_MDA8[avg_MDA8.month == month]
        data2 = max_MDA8[max_MDA8.month == month]  # filter and plot the data for a specific month
        plt.figure()  # create a new figure for each month
        plt.plot(data1.datetime, data1.r_mean, color='k',linewidth=2.0,label='average MDA8')
        plt.plot(data2.datetime, data2.r_mean, color='g',linewidth=2.0,label='max MDA8')
        plt.xlim(date(2009, 1, 1), date(2020, 12, 31))
        plt.ylim(0, 100)
        plt.title(f'Month: {month}')
        plt.ylabel('MDA8 (ppb)')
        plt.xlabel('Year')
        plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.15))
        plt.tight_layout()
```

However, the output is giving me 9 total plots: April_avg/April_max, April_avg/May_max, April_avg/June_max; May_avg/April_max, etc...

I just want to compare April_avg/April_max, May_avg/May_max, June_avg/June_max.

**EDIT**
I'm sorry, I was wrong. The loop isn't plotting the code incorrectly, just printing 3 versions of each graph. Any advice on how to prevent it from duplicating the graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note how you've overloaded `month` in your nested loops:

```
for month in avg_MDA8.month.unique():
    for month in max_MDA8.month.unique():
```

Every time you try to set `month` in the outer loop, the inner loop immediately destroys that value.  Your description says that you want to get corresponding elements, and iterate through the months *once*, in parallel.  Do this more simply: the unique months are the *same* set in both `avg` and `max`, right?  So iterate through the months, regardless of where you got them.  Use only one loop:

```
for month in avg_MDA8.month.unique():
    data1 = avg_MDA8[avg_MDA8.month == month]
    data2 = max_MDA8[max_MDA8.month == month]
```

`month` now takes on each desired value exactly once.